# I am trying to change the image of card on hover Please only CSS solution

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to change the card's image as the user places it on it (hover). I tried the below code but with this code:

```css
.card {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto 0px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card img:hover {
  background-image: url(images/hijab-icon-black-vector-illustration-260nw-1712786086.jpg);
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use the `background-image` approach, put it on the non `:hover` state. Then change the opacity of the `img` on `:hover`.

```css
.card {
  height: auto;
  /*min-width: 90%;*/
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px auto 0px;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=behind');
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=front" alt="" />
</div>
```